# Regular expression to exclude specific words but allow certain patterns

Tags: php, regex

I am generating a regular expression that can contain any *letters* or numbers or an underscore `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` but not contain words that exactly match `log`, `login` and lastly `test`.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Both are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ^(?!(^test$)|(^log$)|(^login$))([A-Za-z0-9_-/]+)$
```

Did the trick for me. Thanks for your answers guys

Answer (score 3):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
\b(?!log(?:in)?|test)\w+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ7cL4/1)

`(?!log(?:in)?|test)` is negative lookahead, that will fail the match if any given words `log,login,test` are present.

Comment: @Spidi: You can even make it case insensitive as well with a `(?i:)` construct. See anubhava's [updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ7cL4/2).

Comment: Thanks Jan. OP can also use /I modifier to make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below regular expression should do the trick

```
^((?!log|login|test)[a-zA-Z0-9_])*$
```

Comment: Well, what can I say, you [think wrong](https://regex101.com/r/gQ7cL4/3) - the anchors destroy everything. Additionally, they are redundant (twice).

Comment: sorry my bad. I thought "log", "login", "test" cases are excluded only. Edited.

Comment: ^(?!(^test$)|(^log$)|(^login$))([A-Za-z0-9_-/]+)$ solved it for me. Thanks for your replies guys!